# Including Capybara::DSL crashes all of my tests with wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, rspec-rails, phantomjs, poltergeist

I am still trying to resolve the fundamental issue outlined in this question: [Rails Phantomjs, poltergeist, and Capybara not playing well together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572034/rails-phantomjs-poltergeist-and-capybara-not-playing-well-together/13721740#13721740)

Basically all of my tests are running fine, but I can't get a valid rendering of a screen using PhantomJS / Poltergeist / Capybara from my rspec tests.

With the small script provided by @theSociable.me (if I run that test ALONE) I **can** get a rendering of one of my screens through Poltergeist/Capbybara!  Great!

*However*, when I add the line **include Capybara::DSL** into my tests, they ALL start failing with this error:

```
 Failure/Error: visit signin_path
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

which, if I follow the backtrace:

```
# ./app/models/user.rb:118:in `authenticate_with_salt'
# ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:67:in `user_from_remember_token'
# ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:25:in `current_user'
# ./app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:31:in `signed_in?'
# ./app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb__1456931984656374710_70286761365040'
# ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___847298267570209394_70286745935080'
# ./spec/requests/parties_spec.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

appears to be a problem with my **visit signin_path** line

..Any ideas why including Capybara::DSL into my project suddenly causes all of these massive failures around authentication/signin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dave, I'd have to see the contents of your request spec but it's likely you're running Capybara 2.x which requires integration specs to be placed inside of `spec/features` and not `spec/requests`.

`spec/requests` is now reserved for API testing (direct GET requests, status code and redirect assertions, etc.) which is why it doesn't automatically receive the Capybara DSL — whereas any spec placed inside of `spec/features` does.

We had a similar issue attempting to give access to the Capybara DSL to our request specs because we needed to (although I'm not convinced it's a good idea yet). This is the solution I ended up with, and it worked for us.

Instead of including the Capybara DSL in the global scope you need to include it within the RSpec configuration block, like this:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL, type: :request
end
```

The `type: :request` part ensures that the DSL is only included for tests that match this specific type, based on the directory structure I believe. This didn't seem to interfere with other tests (feature specs for instance) having access to the Capybara DSL.

Hope it solves your problem.